# Nginx error_page not working for ngx_http_limit_conn_module

Tags: nginx, html

I have an http block where i define `limit_conn_zone` like so:
`limit_conn_zone $host zone=test:10m;`
and i have a reference to another `.conf` file where I have my server configuration

```
server {
..
...
limit_conn_dry_run off;
limit_conn test 2;
limit_conn_log_level error;
limit_conn_status 429;
error_page 429 /429.html;
...
....
..
error_page  429     /429.html;
location = /429.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/error;
 }
```

I have verified that `429.html` file exists in  `/usr/share/nginx/error`. My goal is that
I want to have my own custom error page shown instead of nginx's default error page(which is what is happening currently). Am I missing something? I tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471131/is-there-a-way-to-display-an-error-for-the-user-when-using-nginx-limit-conn-modu but didn't get anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I know I have duplicate `error_page` but that shouldn't matter

Comment: Where does your custom error page come from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton its located in `/usr/share/nginx/error/429.html`